# Linux shared libs distribution with rpath doesn't work on remote machine

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opengl

I have executable,which I need to deploy on Google Compute engine instance.
The executable is written in C++ and is dependent on doezens of shard libraries. I read carefully [some articles](https://aimlesslygoingforward.com/blog/2014/01/19/bundling-shared-libraries-on-linux/) to understand how Linux people do that. So I chose **rpath**. I put everything into a folder called `shared` and put

```
-Wl,--rpath=\\$$$ORIGIN/shared/
```

Into linker's option. The syntax is a bit fancy,but that's how it should look in CodeLite IDE. I checked that the executable loads during runtime libs from that location. Then I uploaded it to GC instance.But when I launch the app I am getting error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

libGLEW.so is indeed one of the first libs the app is trying to load.And its binary resides in the 'shared' folder. I tried to re-upload,reboot machine,run as su, open permissions... Nothing helps. My local machine as well as remote instance run the same OS (Ubuntu 16.04) What can be wrong with that?

Now,more regarding **OpenGL**:

**UPDATE:** I see now why libGLEW.so.1.13 can't be loaded.The libGLEW program loads its shared libs in runtime from default location.I tried to change the GLEW src code to load from my `shared` folder path. But for some reason if I load libGL.so not from the system path but from my shared folder, it doesn't load OpenGL function pointers,even though the SO loads into memory ok. I got rid of GLEW lib completely and tried to load GL functions manually.But again,if I load libGL.so not from default system location,it fails to load GL function addresses. Same problem I have for other libs. For example FFMPEG libavformat etc. Some of them load libx264 and libx265 from default location,so my shared folder's dependencies are completely ignored in this case. Is there way to tell all those libs to load from my location? I see rpath impacts only the binary which I compile with this linker option. I mean,it should be possible to set it up,otherwise how 3rd party software is distributed on Linux (like web browsers ,or games)?

Comment: Try running `ldd your_executable` and `ldd libGLEW.so.1.13` on both machines to check if some 3rd library is missing.

Comment: I did.I can see the same dependencies on both sides.One lib I don't have in my shared folder - linux-vdso.so.1. And I can't find it. But that's a lib loaded by a kernel,from what I understood.Can it be the source of the issue?